# asp.net setting dropdown selected value returns error

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

good morning,

i am having trouble setting the selected value of a dropdownlist in **ASP.NET** from a saved record on my MSSQL 2008 Server.

to elaborate more the dropdown contains a list of countries which after selecting the desired country i will insert it on my MSSQL 2008 Server now i made an edit record page what i am doing is pulling the record from MSSQL 2008 Server and setting it as the selected value of the dropdown here is the code:

```
Dim rogue As New transactionalDataContext
        Dim toupdate = rogue.tbl_personal_informations.Where(Function(update) update.pid = Request.QueryString("pid").ToString).SingleOrDefault

        ciz.Items.FindByValue(toupdate.citizenship.ToLower).Selected = True
```

omitted the code was long

now playing with the DropDown if the data that i pulled from MSSQL Server is the first item on the DropDown list it works with out error but say i choose chinese from the list whicj is almost 20th on the list it returns an error dropdownlist cannot set selectedvalue

it is a bid odd when you look at it but i am out of sorts.

a little help will do.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the solution i found was to clear first the selection before setting the selected value
code below:

```
DropDownList.ClearSelection()
```